# How to set the name of an instance of something to the value of an integer?

Tags: java

I already tried this:

```
public static void accountTypeSavings() {
    boolean b = true;
    while (b) {
        String startBalanceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting balance in dollars without the dollar sign.");
        try {
            double startBalance = Double.parseDouble(startBalanceString);
            int accountID = 1;
            SavingsAccount accountID = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);
            accountID += 1;
            b = false;
        }
        catch (final Exception ignored) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only enter numbers, please.");
        }
    }
}
```

Creating an integer and setting the name of the savings account to the integer. But that's giving me the error "Duplicate local variable accountID".

When using my application, I want to get this:

```
SavingsAccount sa1 = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);
SavingsAccount sa2 = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);
SavingsAccount sa3 = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);
```

The parameters are variables whose are already initialized!

I want to set the name of the new SavingsAccount to the accountID's value. So if I create a new instance of a SavingsAccount, I want my application to set it's name to sa1. And if I create another one after that, name it sa2, sa3, sa4, etc.

PS: Holder is a string, it contains the name of someone! It's not an integer!

I hope you understand what I mean!

Comment: I'm getting "Duplicate local variable accountID".

Comment: accountTypeSavings is not a class.Its a function!!

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but to me, it looks that you want to do something like for example `new SavingsAccount("acc1", 100.0);` and then set the variable name of that SavingsAccount instance to `acc1` so that you can do something like: `acc1.getBalance()`. This is however simply not possible.

Comment: No. Almost right. If I'm creating a new Savings account by using the GUI, I want it to create a line like this: `SavingsAccount 1 = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);`. And if I create another one I want my application to create this line: `SavingsAccount 2 = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);`

Edit:

The holder is a string containing a name. It's already set to a name (like Sander de Lange) by using a different method.

Comment: Java variables can not start with numbers.So not possible!

Comment: Why would you even need this? Where would you use the variable names 1, 2, etc? BTW, have you ever heard of arrays or lists?

Comment: Dude, I'm just in java for about two weeks. I was just watching a tutorial about arraylists made by Brandonio Productions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if there comes a second savings account, how do I make the application create a savings account with the name sa2, and after that one with the name sa3 etc?

Declare a global int, let's say index.

```
private int index;
```

Set it to 1 in your constructor:

```
this.index = 1;
```

Each time someone creates a savings account, increase index.

```
SavingsAccount accountID = new SavingsAccount(holder + index++, startBalance);
```

This will add the current value of `index` to the end of the `holder` string, then increase the value of `index`.

**Edit**

Okay, so I get what you mean, but a variable can not start with, or be named solely a number. Instead, why not add those accounts to an `array` or a `List` implementation?

```
List<SavingsAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("Dave", something);
accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("Bill", somethingElse);
```

Then to get each account, you can use something like this:

```
accounts.get(1);
```

**NOTE**: This list is 0 based. Which means `accounts.get(0);` will get the first item.

Comment: Urgh.. I don't want that. I'm not english so it's very hard to explain, especially when I'm talking about coding. I'm only 13 years old.
but if I use that, I'll get a problem too. Because if I create multiple savings accounts, they will be all named accountID. THAT's where my problem is.

Comment: You want to dynamically NAME the variables. I see. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: I've just tried your idea, but there's an error popping up: Cannot instantiate the type List<SavingsAccount>. There's a red line under the word List in this part: `= new List<SavingsAccount>();`. [Here's my complete code](http://pastebin.com/ZGbUjYGv)

Comment: I apologize. A careless mistake on my part. Replace `new List< blah blah blah` with `new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();`

Answer (score 1):

```
int accountID = 1;
SavingsAccount accountID = new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance);
```

You can't have 2 variables with the same name.

Comment: But how do I set the savings account's name to the value of the accountID integer?

Comment: With the informations you provided, it's impossible to tell. Please add code for `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: What code should I use?? I'm a java noob. I was just toying around.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a list.So add another static variable savingsAccountList

```
public static List<SavingsAccount> savingsAccountList = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
```

You can take an auto incrementing variable m and use it as a static class variable:

```
public static int m=0;

public static void accountTypeSavings() {
        boolean b = true;

        holder="holderName"
        while (b) {
            String startBalanceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting balance in dollars without the dollar sign.");
            try {
                double startBalance = Double.parseDouble(startBalanceString);
                SavingsAccount sa = new SavingsAccount(holder + m, startBalance);
                m++
                savingsAccountList.add(sa)
                b = false;
            }
            catch (final Exception ignored) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only enter numbers, please.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you need to import java.util.List.

Comment: That's because the holder is a string. It contains the name of the bank account owner. ++ only works with integers and doubles.

Comment: I initialized the holder STRING in a different method. [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/4AEjh54R)

Comment: so remove the line holder="holderName." It should work! Or simply initialize holder as holder="" wherever u have initialized.

Comment: Nobody understands it. You can't do this:

`SavingsAccount sa1 = new SavingsAccount("holder", startBalance);`
`SavingsAccount sa1 = new SavingsAccount("holder1", startBalance);`

Because SA1 already exists. It has nothing to do with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to *store* the savings in a list outside of your method. I suggest a field:

```
private static List<SavingsAccount> savingsAccounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
```

and your method could go like this:

```
public static void accountTypeSavings() {
    boolean b = true;
    while (b) {
        String startBalanceString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting balance in dollars without the dollar sign.");
        try {
            double startBalance = Double.parseDouble(startBalanceString);
            savingAccounts.add(new SavingsAccount(holder, startBalance));
            b = false;
        }
        catch (final Exception ignored) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only enter numbers, please.");
        }
    }
}
```

Later you can access the saving accounts from the list to modify their properties:

```
savingAccounts.get(0).addAmount(amount); // something like this to add money to the first account
```